# Make code changed by jQuery visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, code-generation

how can I make code generated or changed by jQuery (JavaScript) visible? Showing the plain code in the browser (e.g. Firefox) only shows the elements before they were changed and manipulated by jQuery/JavaScript.

Are there tools (for Firefox?) where I can make the live code visible?

Comment: Are you talking about showing code on your site or do you just want to see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using Firebug? this will allow you to see the HTML after it has been manipulated

Comment: Oh didn't know that Firebug can show me the changed HTML code ... Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) which does exactly what you need and much much more

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using Firebug or some other plugin, in Firefox you can highlight the text, right click and select "Show source".

Answer (score 0):

Use an object inspector so you can see the live DOM like Firebug or the built-in Chrome or Safari Inspectors.  In any of those tools, you just right click on an object in the web page and select "Inspect Element" and a whole live DOM hierarchy opens up in a window for you to inspect what is really in the web page at this moment.

Here's what it looks like in Chrome when I right click on an object in a live StackOverflow page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're displaying the initial code via a javascript function call, then just call that function again after the update.